# Apache CXF WebServices Client Error

Tags: soap, cxf, wsse

I have a client that I generate using the WSDL that I have. When I tried to connect to this WebService, I get the following error:

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:161)
```

The actual server that hosts the WebService expects a SOAP message that contains the security header like:

```
<soapenv:Header>

  <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">

  <o:UsernameToken u:Id="XXXX">

    <o:Username>XXXX</o:Username>

    <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXXX</o:Password>

  </o:UsernameToken>

  </o:Security>

</soapenv:Header>
```

How to get this along with my SOAP message that gets generated when the request is made? This is what I do in my code to call the WebService:

```
val factory = new org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean()
factory.setServiceClass(classOf[MyWebService])

// if there is an address, then let's set it!
factory.setAddress("https://my/server/address/MyWebService.svc")

// log incoming and outgoing

factory.getInInterceptors.add(new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor())
factory.getOutInterceptors.add(new org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor())

val myServiceClient = factory.create().asInstanceOf[MyWebService]
myServiceClient.myMethod("param")
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you have to do to get this working:

```
1. Add the following dependencies (if you have not added it already)
    "org.apache.cxf" % "cxf-rt-ws-security" % "3.1.4",
    "org.apache.ws.security" % "wss4j" % "1.6.13",

2. In the place where you set information in the client proxy, add the following:

        val myWebService = factory.create().asInstanceOf[MyWebService]
        val proxy = ClientProxy.getClient(myWebService) 
        val endpoint = proxy.getEndpoint

        import collection.JavaConversions._
        val callbackHandler = new CallbackHandler {
          override def handle(callbacks: Array[Callback]): Unit = {
            val pc = callbacks(0).asInstanceOf[WSPasswordCallback]
            pc.setPassword("your password")
          }
        }

        val outProps = Map(
          WSHandlerConstants.ACTION -> WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN,
          WSHandlerConstants.USER -> "Your user name",
          WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE -> WSConstants.PW_TEXT
        )
        outProps.updated(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, callbackHandler)

        val wssOut = new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps)
        endpoint.getOutInterceptors.add(wssOut)
        // set the credentials, timeouts etc
        proxy.getRequestContext().put("password", "your password")
```